# Check input if it is a letter, number, or special character in assembly language

Tags: assembly

Just like the title, I’m sorry but i’m really new to this language and it would greatly help if someone could help me.

Comment: assembly is not a language. It must always go along with an architecture. Please add the relevant tags

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the character you are currently reading to their hex value '0-9' in hex is 0x30-0x39, 'A-Z' is 0x41-0x5A and 'a-z' 0x61-0x7A. Lookup a hex table to see what other special characters you want to compare against.

Comment: Thats where my problem is. I don’t understand the CMP in assembly. Ive read that CMP is the if statement in assembly but i dont know how to code it in

Comment: CMP AX, 0x30 basically compared what value is in AX with '0' and sets flags. The Jump Command utilizes those flags and executes depending on what you want the program to do. So on the next line you can use JE(Jump if equal) if AX is 0, JLE(Jump if less than) if AX is less than 0and JGE(Jump if greater than) if AX is greater than 0.

Comment: @AlaguVeerappan: You can detect alphabetic characters (lower and upper case) with one range-check using  `or al, 0x20` (force to lowercase) / `sub al, 'a'` / `cmp al, 'z'-'a'` / `ja not_alphabetic`, if we're talking about x86.  [What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](//stackoverflow.com/a/54585515) shows a C version.